# How can we achieve the below output using two source tables (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

Can you please help me in getting the below output using 2 different tables?

Table 1: has below data
[image]

Table 2: has below data

[image]

The output table should be with below data:

[image]

Please help me to achieve this output, Sorry if I missed anything

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Can you share your coding attempt at this problem? It can be a good starter for a code that maybe needs just a quick fix. @SravanReddy

Comment: I tried with the below 2 queries , and I am not getting any clue to go further.       insert into target(id,name1,name2)
select src1.id,src1.name1,src2.name2 from src1
left outer join src2
on src1.id=src2.id-- and src1.id=src2.id

UPDATE target a
   SET name = a.name1
FROM target b
WHERE a.name1= b.name2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the sub-select into 3 separate queries and then use `UNION` to both "glue" the results set together and de-duplicate the results set where the `name1` columns match between the two table e.g. "John".

Something like this :

```
insert into target(id,name1,name2,name3)
select src1.id,src1.name1,src2.name1,src1.name1
from src1
inner join src2 on src1.id = src2.id
where src1.name1 is not null
and src2.name1 is not null
union
select src1.id,src1.name1,src2.name1,src2.name1
from src1
inner join src2 on src1.id = src2.id
where src1.name1 is not null
and src2.name1 is not null
union
select src1.id,src1.name1,src2.name1,coalesce(src1.name1,src2.name1)
from table1 src1
inner join table2 src2 on src1.id = src2.id
where src1.name1 is null
or src2.name1 is null
order by 1
```

Handling the `null` values in a separate select since `UNION` will not de-duplicate `null` values